# BigQuery Google Analytics sessionsWithEvent metric

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm having trouble creating a BigQuery query that will allow for me to fetch the Google Analytics **ga:sessionsWithEvent** metric.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(concat(fullvisitorid, string(visitid))) AS distinctVisitIds
FROM
  (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([xxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-11-30'), TIMESTAMP('2016-12-26')))
WHERE
  hits.type='EVENT'
```

The logic in the query above seems sound - get all the rows that have a hit.type of 'EVENT' and sum up the exact count of distinct fullVisitorId/VisitId results - aka. the number of unique sessions with an event.

But the numbers I get from here are close but higher than what I get using [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)

Thank you.

**EDIT: Addressing comment below to use wider date range with date filter**

With date range +-5 days, this makes the query

```
SELECT
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(concat(fullvisitorid, string(visitid))) AS distinctVisitIds
FROM
  (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([xxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-11-25'), TIMESTAMP('2016-12-31')))
WHERE
  hits.type='EVENT'
  AND ('20161130'<=date AND date<='20161226')
```

Unfortunately I still get the same number

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on the table dates, usually even on later days you can have metrics from previous days. Instead use a larger date range on from and exact date range on columns.

AFAIK also the data explorer does approximations.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my query with +/- 5 days and used a date filter on the session but get the same result. Query explorer also says "Contains sampled data:No", which means that the result should be accurate.

Comment: ok cool, I misread your question was thinking the numbers are smaller, but you say your numbers in BQ is higher, that is good. See one answer here explains why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410832/biqquery-vs-google-analytics-which-data-is-more-accurate?rq=1

Comment: That linked question mentions data sampling for the API (which query explorer runs on). This would make sense if query explorer showed "Contains sampled data:Yes" but for me it says "No" which means there should be no sampling involved and it should match BigQuery unsampled data.

Comment: since you already have premium as you got analytics export, you can create a support ticket and ask if you are seeing missing data, or what could be the discrepancies

Comment: I wish that were true >..< I tried for a previous query issue but was told by the support line that they do not handle any query-related questions. They actually referred me back to StackOverflow. A nice way to treat a premium customer.

Comment: please post the case number and a google engineer may check it