# Total Sessions in BigQuery vs Google Analytics Reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm just learning BigQuery so this might be a dumb question, but we want to get some statistics there and one of those is the total sessions in a given day.

To do so, I've queried in BQ:

```
select sum(sessions) as total_sessions from (
  select
    fullvisitorid,
    count(distinct visitid) as sessions,
    from (table_query([40663402], 'timestamp(right(table_id,8)) between timestamp("20150519") and timestamp("20150519")'))
    group each by fullvisitorid
)
```

(I'm using the `table_query` because later on we might increase the range of days)

This results in `1,075,137`.

But in our Google Analytics Reports, in the "Audience Overview" section, the same day results:

`This report is based on 1,026,641 sessions (100% of sessions).`

There's always this difference of roughly ~5% despite of the day. So I'm wondering, even though the query is quite simple, is there any mistake we've made?

Is this difference expected to happen? I read through BigQuery's documentation but couldn't find anything on this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What happens if you try EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(visitid) instead?

Comment: Hi @FelipeHoffa. I tried this one as well but got the same result.

Comment: Im still having this issue. Did you manage to find out what the cause was?

Comment: hi @tomb, yes, we did figure that out. We got into contact with Gooogle's technical support and they told us that in Google Analytics reports we only have sessions that had some "event" interaction. In Bigquery on the other hand contains all sessions with or without events being fired. In order to get the same result as analytics you have to add "totals.visits = 1" in a where clause. I'll write an answer to this question to explain a bit better ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After posting the question we got into contact with Google support and found that in Google Analytics only sessions that had an "event" being fired  are actually counted.

In Bigquery you will find all sessions regardless whether they had an interaction or not.

In order to find the same result as in GA, you should filter by sessions with `totals.visits = 1` in your BQ query (`totals.visits` is 1 only for sessions that had an event being fired).

That is:

```
select sum(sessions) as total_sessions from (
  select
    fullvisitorid,
    count(distinct visitid) as sessions,
    from (table_query([40663402], 'timestamp(right(table_id,8)) between timestamp("20150519") and timestamp("20150519")'))
    where totals.visits = 1
    group each by fullvisitorid
)
```

Comment: Do you know how to count sessions per hour ? Unfortunately grouping by fullVisitorId, hits.hour or just filtering out specific hour in where section didnt give me the same results as I have in google analytics. SELECT
fullvisitorid,
h.hour,
count(distinct visitid) as sessions,  
FROM  `XXX.ga_sessions_*`, 
UNNEST(hits) as h
WHERE 
(_table_suffix = '20210907' )
AND totals.visits = 1
--AND h.hour = 8
group by fullvisitorid, h.hour

Comment: @Agnieszka I recommend posting a new question describing your query, desired results and current ones. Not sure why this is happening but the problem may be related to the unnesting process happening on the hits field which ends up duplicating rows and distorts results if not handled properly.

Answer (score 18):

[standardsql](/questions/tagged/standardsql)

Simply `SUM(totals.visits)` or when using `COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING) ))` make sure `totals.visits=1`!

If you use `visitId` and you are not grouping per day, you will combine midnight-split-sessions!

Here are all scenarios:

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING) )) allSessionsUniquePerDay,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitId AS STRING) )) allSessionsUniquePerSelectedTimeframe,
  sum(totals.visits) interactiveSessionsUniquePerDay, -- equals GA UI sessions
  COUNT(DISTINCT IF(totals.visits=1, CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitId AS STRING)), NULL) ) interactiveSessionsUniquePerSelectedTimeframe,
  SUM(IF(totals.visits=1,0,1)) nonInteractiveSessions
FROM
  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_2017102*`
```

Wrap up:

- `fullVisitorId` + `visitId`: useful to reconnect midnight-splits
- `fullVisitorId` + `visitStartTime`: useful to take splits into account
- `totals.visits=1` for interaction sessions
- `fullVisitorId` + `visitStartTime` where `totals.visits=1`: GA UI sessions (in case you need a session id)
- `SUM(totals.visits)`: simple GA UI sessions
- `fullVisitorId` + `visitId` where `totals.visits=1` and `GROUP BY date`: GA UI sessions with too many chances for errors and misunderstandings

Comment: `midnight-split-sessions` --- why is it not documented... I wasted so much time because of it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be due to "COUNT DISTINCT".

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609219/bigquery-countdistinct-value-vs-countvalue):

> COUNT DISTINCT is a statistical approximation for all results greater than 1000

You could try setting an additional COUNT parameter to improve accuracy at the expense of performance (see post), but I would first try:

```
SELECT COUNT( CONCAT( fullvisitorid,'_', STRING(visitid))) as sessions 
from (table_query([40663402], 'timestamp(right(table_id,8)) between 
timestamp("20150519") and timestamp("20150519")'))
```

Comment: I used EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT as well for this query but got the same result. Not sure yet what went wrong

Comment: The above worked for me, but a key difference is that our site has much lower daily sessions. Maybe reach out to Google under the support that comes with a premium GA account... be sure to share any insights!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was this:

```
SELECT count(distinct sessionId) FROM(
   SELECT CONCAT(clientId, "-", visitNumber, "-", date) as sessionId FROM `project-id.dataset-id.ga_sessions_*`
   WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN "20191001" AND "20191031" AND totals.visits = 1)
```

The explanation (found very well written in
this article: https://adswerve.com/blog/google-analytics-bigquery-tips-users-sessions-part-one/) is that when counting and dealing with sessions we should be careful because by default, Google Analytics breaks sessions that carryover midnight (time zone of the view). Therefore a same session can end up in two daily tables:

[Image from article mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9nd1.png)

The code provided creates a sessionID by combining:
client id + visit number + date
while acknowledging the session break; the result will be in a human-readable format. Finally to match sessions in the Google Analytics UI, make sure to filter to only those with totals.visits = 1.

Comment: It would be preferable if you could explain the code here instead of forcing a click-through.