# Google Analytics Funnel Analysis using Big Query

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I want to do funnel analysis for my Google Analytics form submission data using BigQuery. I am reading [this article](http://online-behavior.com/analytics/funnel-analysis) to get started but I have some questions.

This article only explains about creating a funnel using pages. What if I have a page and event? For example, my typical form funnel flow will be page A > user clicks on Next button on page A > reaches page B > user clicks on Submit button on page B. There is no Thank You page so final submit button will be end of my funnel (which I use event tracking to track the number of clicks).

Based on the article, I can create query as below (from page A to page B).

```
SELECT
  s0.fullVisitorId,
  s0.visitId,
  s0.firstHit,
  s1.firstHit
FROM (
SELECT
    fullVisitorId,
    visitId,
    MIN(hits.hitNumber) AS firstHit
    FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE([xxx.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-11-01'), 
    TIMESTAMP('2016-11-30'))
    WHERE
    REGEXP_MATCH(hits.page.pagePath, '/pageA/')
    AND totals.visits = 1
    GROUP BY
    fullVisitorId,
    visitId) s0
LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH (
SELECT
    fullVisitorId,
    visitId,
    MIN(hits.hitNumber) AS firstHit
    FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE([xxx.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2016-11-01'), 
    TIMESTAMP('2016-11-30'))
    WHERE
    REGEXP_MATCH(hits.page.pagePath, '/pageB/')
    AND totals.visits = 1
    GROUP BY
    fullVisitorId,
    visitId) s1
ON
    s0.fullVisitorID = s1.fullVisitorID
    AND s0.visitID = s1.visitID
```

How can I add event tracking into this? Thank you so much.

Comment: How are you tracking the click event? If it's by the `ga_event` function then you'll have to query the field `hits.eventinfo` filtering for the `category`, `action` and `label` whereas if the tracking is made through `customdimensions` then you'll have to query for the field `hits.customdimensions` on a particular `index` and `value`.

Comment: Thanks! and how do I join these queries together? Can I join by visit ID?

Comment: For what I understood you already did the `join` operation using the `left join`. If you want to use the `click` event as well you'd need to know where this event is being saved in your dataset (either in field `hits.eventinfo` or `hits.customdimensions`)

Comment: Thanks @Will I found the way to make it work. not sure I am asking the right question here but do you know why GA numbers and BigQuery numbers are a bit different?

Comment: Maybe this one explains the differences you are observing:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419771/total-sessions-in-bigquery-vs-google-analytics-reports

Comment: Did you get it working?