# BigQuery Session & Hit level understanding

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I want to ask about your knowledge regarding the concept of Events.

Hit level 
Session Level

How in BigQuery (standard SQL) how i can map mind this logic, and also

**Sessions
Events Per Session 
Unique Events**

Please can somebody guide me to understand these concepts?

totals.visitors is Session 
sometime 
visitId is taken as Session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to achieve that you need to grapple a little with a few different concepts. The first being "what is a session" in GA lingo. you can find that [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en). A session is a collection of hits. A hit is one of the following: pageview, event, social interaction or transaction.

Now to see how that is represented in the BQ schema, you can look [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en). `visitId` and `visitorId` will help you define a session (as opposed to a user).

Then you can count the number of `totals.hits` that are events of the type you want.

It could look something like:

```
select visitId, 
sum(case when hits.type = "EVENT" then totals.hits else 0) from 
dataset.table_* group by 1
```

That should work to get you an overview. If you need to slice and dice the event details  (i.e. `hits.eventInfo.*`) then I suggest you make a query for all the `visitId` and one for all the relevant events and their respective `visitId`

I hope that works!

Cheers

Comment: There are some mistakes in your answer: `visitorId` is deprecated it should be `fullVisitorId`. Your query is not working in standard sql. In legacy sql you would be summing all hits of a session `totals.hits` per every hit `hits.type`. You are only grouping by `visitId` - you should use `fullvisitorid` and `visitstarttime` for GA sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of these concepts like this:

- every row is a session
- technically every row with totals.visits=1 is a valid session
- `hits` is an array containing structs which contain information for every hit

You can write subqueries on arrays - basically treat them as tables. I'd recommend to study [Working with Arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays) and apply/transfer every exercise directly to `hits`, if possible.

*Example for subqueries on session level*

```sql
SELECT
  fullvisitorid,
  visitStartTime,
  (SELECT SUM(IF(type='EVENT',1,0)) FROM UNNEST(hits)) events,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(eventInfo.eventCategory,eventInfo.eventAction,eventInfo.eventLabel) ) 
    FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE type='EVENT') uniqueEvents,
  (SELECT SUM(IF(type='PAGE',1,0)) FROM UNNEST(hits)) pageviews
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`
WHERE
  totals.visits=1
LIMIT
  1000
```

*Example for Flattening to hit level*

There's also the possibility to use fields in arrays for grouping if you cross join arrays with their parent row

```sql
SELECT
  h.type,
  COUNT(1) hits
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801` AS t CROSS JOIN t.hits AS h
WHERE
  totals.visits=1
GROUP BY 
  1
```

Regarding the relation between visitId and Sessions you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419771/total-sessions-in-bigquery-vs-google-analytics-reports/46977975#46977975).