# Can't match GA advanced segment and BigQuery results

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm using a simple GA advanced segment: 
[image]

And it returns 10,440 sessions in GA interface for a single day.

When I try to do something similar in BigQuery using Standard SQL I get different results:

```
SELECT fullVisitorId, visitStartTime
FROM `project.id.ga_sessions_20181001`
where EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) h 
  WHERE h.type  = 'PAGE'
  AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, r'/signup/.*'));
```

This returns 10,137 sessions for the same day. And this:

```
SELECT fullVisitorId, visitStartTime
FROM `project.id.ga_sessions_20181001`
where EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) h 
  WHERE AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(page.pagePath, r'/signup/.*'));
```

Returns 10,564 sessions for the same day. How to get them to match the GA interface?

Comment: Don't you need to count the distinct number of `fullVisitorId`? There have been some past similar questions if you do a bit of searching, too, which may be useful.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm interested in sessions, not users. Why should I count the users?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419771/total-sessions-in-bigquery-vs-google-analytics-reports/46977975#46977975 hth!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sessions* as a metric in GA and BigQuery is a pre-aggregated metric to allow for faster processing. To match GA, you need to use `SUM(totals.visits)`, rather than the `COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullVisitorId,CAST(visitId as STRING)))` . Visits to your site where a user only triggers non-interaction events (and no pageviews) will result in a visitId and a record in BigQuery with a `totals.visits` value of zero, but can be queried and reported on using segments for users, or *Unique Dimension Combinations*.

BigQuery Query View:
[image]

Google Analytics Dasboard View:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation! Any idea why segment condition event category = User login and event action matches RegEx [0-9] won't match EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) h WHERE eventInfo.eventCategory = 'User login' AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(eventInfo.eventAction, r'^[0-9]') )

Comment: Hi, sorry about the delay and thanks for accepting my answer. I'd imagine the BigQuery result will be counting total events, where the other is going to count visits that include the event. I can help debug if you still haven't figured this out?

Comment: It seems combining event category and event action in advanced segment as condition and as sequence returns different results. I managed to match the sequence one with the BQ query, but can't match the condition one.