# Replicating Google Analytics All Sessions for a Custom Dimension in In BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to replicate sessions by a custom dimension in BigQuery to the Google Analytics AII. I am only a few sessions off and I can't figure out what how to get an exact match.

My current understanding is that GA breaks sessions at midnight (because its data model relies on processing in day chunks). I tired to take this into account with the code below, but something is not quite right. Does anyone know how to get an exact match?

```
SELECT
  CD12,
  SUM(sessions) AS sessions
FROM (
   SELECT
   CD12,
   CASE WHEN hitNumber = first_hit THEN visits ELSE 0 END AS sessions
   FROM (
        SELECT
            fullVisitorId,
            visitStartTime,
            totals.visits,
            hits.hitNumber,
            CASE WHEN cd.index = 12 THEN cd.value END AS CD12,
            MIN(hits.hitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime) AS first_hit
         FROM `data-....`,
            UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
            UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) AS cd
        )
    )
WHERE CD12 ='0'
GROUP BY 
CD12
ORDER BY
  sessions DESC
```

Comment: The best answer to this question pointed some detail you might have missed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419771/total-sessions-in-bigquery-vs-google-analytics-reports

Comment: Thanks for sending this along I was not able to pinpoint the problem. Do you happen to know if there is some information out there for session for a custom dimension that would match in BigQuery?