# BigQuery New Users count strongly differ from displayed Firebase Analytics data

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery

During my inspections, I have found that after the 14th of January, new users count strongly differs between Google BigQuery and Google Firebase Analytics.

The discrepancy is higher than the traditional 0.5-2% rate that can be attributed to the HyperLogLog algorithm used to make computation faster.

I wasn't able to find a precise answer on how exactly new users are computed on Firebase Analytics to create the same query and get identical queries results. Since the discrepancy is above the 30% range, now the problem magnitude is more significant.

Do you have the same problem? How can I explain better this strange behavior? (by run other queries and try to find more details about the issue)

This is the query used to compare results:

```
SELECT APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(user_pseudo_id),event_date FROM `practical-bot-198011.analytics_184597160.events_*`
where event_name = 'first_open' and _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20200110' AND '20200127'
GROUP BY event_date
ORDER BY event_date ASC
```

and this is the result I get:

[image: Result of the above query]

but in the Google Firebase Analytics Dashboard:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason of count in Analytics dashboard doesn't match BigQuery results is that the data for the most recent three days is being updated every 4-5 hours in Analytics. In BigQuery data is only exported once per day. Queries which include the most recent three days will show different results between Analytics and BigQuery.

`Count(distinct)` is an approximation. To get an exact count of unique IDs, try to use `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT()`. Refer to this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609219/bigquery-countdistinct-value-vs-countvalue) thread.

Additionally, take a look to [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).

Comment: I cannot use  `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT ` because it's Legacy SQL, thus I should use  `COUNT(DISTINCT <exp>) ` which works even if data still differs between BigQuery and GA. I'm not trying to get data from the last few days, so the problem you are referring to should not be relevant.

Comment: You can specify a second parameter, `n`, in `COUNT(DISTINCT [field], n)` which gives the threshold below which exact results are guaranteed. By default, `n` is 1000, but if you give a larger `n`, you will get exact results for `COUNT(DISTINCT)` up to that value of `n`. Look here
https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-countdistinct-field-works-in-google-bigquery/